# Fazer uma sessão expirar

Tags: php, session

Estou tentando colocar na minha página que, se o visitante ficar 20min inativo, a sessão expira, o php destrói a sessão e redireciona o visitante para a página de login. Mas não está funcionando. Meu código está assim:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
$_SESSION['final']  = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (1 * 60) ;
$agora               = time();
if(isset($_SESSION['final'])){
    if($agora > $_SESSION['final']){
      session_destroy();
      header("Location: ../index.php?id=998&tp=bi");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Não fica mais fácil você fazer assim? Eu uso desta maneira em meus sites..

```
header("Refresh: 1200; url=paginadelogin.php");
```

Abraço!